# What's the exact difference between: in, under, below?

Tags: prepositions

What's the exact difference between:

> 1. He is UNDER the water.
> 2. he is BELOW the water.
> 3. He is IN the water.

The answer received states not quiet clearly that in most cases I can use either, IN  and ON. A clearer explanation would be much appreciated, also,  can I say: The man is BELOW the water. If the answer is no, why not?